# Git patch file attached to Outlook email gets modified by it

Tags: git, outlook, attachment, patch, email-attachments

I want to send .patch files that were generated by the `git format-patch` command via Outlook (I have to use Outlook where I work, no need to suggest me otherwise). The goal is only to have my code reviewed by a colleague before pushing my changes to the main repository. When I send my patch files as attachments, a **>** character gets inserted right at the beginning of my patch file.

Ex:

```
>From 7ff70407d24338e928fafcd89115f9844c21691b Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: user <user@company.com>
Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2012 09:55:17 -0400
Subject: [PATCH] Blahblah...
```

This makes it impossible for `git am` to apply the patch on my colleague system.

I don't know (and don't know how to figure it out) how to validate if the modification occurs on the sending end or the receiving end.

Anyone knows what causes this? Are there some settings in Outlook that I should modify in order to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to an old Unix mailbox file format called [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox):

> *mboxo* and *mboxrd* locate the message start by scanning for *From* lines that are typically found in the e-mail message header. If a "From " string occurs at the beginning of a line in either the headers or the body of a message (unlikely for the former for correctly formatted messages, but likely for the latter), the e-mail message must be modified before the message is stored in an mbox mailbox file or the line will be taken as a message boundary. This is typically done by prepending a greater-than sign:
>
> ```
> >From my point of view...
> ```

In your situation, it's impossible (for us) to tell which component of your mail system might be prepending that `>`.

For use with Git, you can either delete the `>`, or you can probably delete the entire line (since the email message headers are not relevant to Git).

Answer (score 1):

> When I send my patch files as attachments, a `>` character gets inserted right at the beginning of my patch file.

Those '`>From`' lines can be escaped now, with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023): "[`git format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e83d57e34a0f36ed383607aac6a015afd3c0ef0f/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch))</sup> learned to honor **`format.mboxrd`** even when sending patches to the standard output stream.

I presented **`mboxrd`** in "[Why is mail command adding extra character ("`>`") to the email?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551388/6309)"

See [commit 4810946](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4810946f6032a973ad752d06a32437bc9bb35e67) (22 Dec 2022) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e83d57e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e83d57e34a0f36ed383607aac6a015afd3c0ef0f), 02 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4810946f6032a973ad752d06a32437bc9bb35e67): support `format.mboxrd` with `--stdout`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Wong</sup>

> `mboxrd` is a more robust output format when used with `--stdout` and needs more exposure.
> Introducing this config knob lets users choose the more robust format for all their `--stdout` uses.
>
> Relying on `--pretty=mboxrd` and including all of `pretty-formats.txt` in the [`git format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4810946f6032a973ad752d06a32437bc9bb35e67/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch))</sup> documentation would likely be confusing to users.
> Furthermore, this setting is useful across multiple invocations.
>
> So introduce `format.mboxrd' as a boolean configuration knob that changes the default` --pretty=email`format to`--pretty=mboxrd`when (and only when)`--stdout` is in use.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4810946f6032a973ad752d06a32437bc9bb35e67/Documentation/config/format.txt#L142-L145):

> ### `format.mboxrd`
>
> A boolean value which enables the robust "mboxrd" format when
> `--stdout` is in use to escape "[`^>+From`](https://regex101.com/r/mqZBl2/1) " lines.

Example:

```
git -c format.mboxrd format-patch --stdout -1 $C~1..$C >patch
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try bouncing off of an smtp server you have?

`git send-email --smtp-server=smtp.gmail.com *.patch`

Would that work?

Or, you could look at http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/12/git-tip-of-week-patches-by-email.html and try the git bundle command. . .

Are you only using github and windows in general, or can you at least use Cygwin for these command line options?