# Why is mail command adding extra character (">") to the email?

Tags: email, unix

Why is mail command adding extra character (">") to the email?

```
Here is the text entry:
From the ...

Here is the text in Email:
>From the ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `From`   (that is `From` with `F` in upper-case, `rom` in lower, followed by a space character) in the beginning of the line marks the beginning of a new  message in the [*mbox*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox#Family) format. The *mbox* format is just really one text file with messages appended to each other.

Quoting from [mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox#Family) (Wikipedia):

> *mboxo* and *mboxrd* locate the message start by scanning for `From` lines that are found before the email message headers. If a `From` string occurs at the beginning of a line in either the header or the body of a message (a mail standard violation for the former, but not for the latter), the email message must be modified before the message is stored in an *mbox* mailbox file or the line will be taken as a message boundary. To avoid misinterpreting a `From` string at the beginning of the line in the email body as the beginning of a new email, some systems "From-munge" the message, typically by prepending a greater-than sign:
>
> ```
> >From my point of view...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That same practice has been introduced in another Linux tool: Git (2.10, June 2016), which teached `format-patch` and `mailsplit` (hence "`am`") how a line that happens to begin with "`From` " in the e-mail message is quoted with "`>`", so that these lines can be restored to their original shape.

See [commit d9925d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9925d1a714a440f4063f64e1bd776194d2dd918), [commit c88098d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c88098d7f19c6322fbd911bb89e2efd246bf75c4), [commit 9f23e04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f23e040615857e3909db51a5420f338c9831b5a) (05 Jun 2016) by [Eric Wong (`ele828`)](https://github.com/ele828).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e25a4de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e25a4ded8a47333a4c71a224927d6df87d7c295e), 06 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### [`pretty`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f23e040615857e3909db51a5420f338c9831b5a): support "`mboxrd`" output format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Wong</sup>
>
> This output format prevents format-patch output from breaking readers if somebody copy+pasted an mbox into a commit message.
>
> Unlike the traditional "`mboxo`" format, "`mboxrd`" is **designed to be fully-reversible**.
>
> "`mboxrd`" also gracefully degrades to showing extra "`>`" in existing "`mboxo`" readers.
>
> This degradation is preferable to breaking message splitting completely, a problem I've seen in "`mboxcl`" due to having multiple, non-existent, or inaccurate `Content-Length` headers.
>
> "`mboxcl2`" is a non-starter since it's inherits the problems of "`mboxcl`" while being completely incompatible with existing tooling based around `mailsplit`.

Documentation in Git 2.27 (Q2 2020):

See [commit 88eaf36](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88eaf361e04fe10a3ffd9f6af466a993e926b45e) (16 Apr 2020) by [Emma Brooks (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e08387d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e08387d32146337e97a9112ed3348f2e3bc3f9f5), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88eaf361e04fe10a3ffd9f6af466a993e926b45e): explain "mboxrd" pretty format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Emma Brooks</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Eric Wong</sup>
>
> The "`mboxrd`" pretty format was introduced in [9f23e04061](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f23e040615857e3909db51a5420f338c9831b5a) (pretty: support "`mboxrd`" output format, 2016-06-05, Git 2.16.0) but wasn't mentioned in the documentation.
>
> ### `mboxrd`
>
> Like 'email', but lines in the commit message starting with "`From` " (preceded by zero or more "`>`") are quoted with "`>`" so they aren't confused as starting a new commit.